# how to set average line in chartcontrol in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

I have a chartcontrol which datasource is datatable and chart shows all employees' workingday by their name.

```
ChartControl chart = chartControl1;

            // Specify data members to bind the chart's series template.
            Series series = new Series("series", ViewType.Bar);
            chartControl1.Series.Add(series);

            chartControl1.Series["series"].DataSource = dataTable;

            series.ArgumentDataMember = dataTable.Columns["Name"].ColumnName;
            series.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { dataTable.Columns["WorkingDay"].ColumnName });

            // Specify the template's series view.
            chart.SeriesTemplate.View = new StackedBarSeriesView();

            //register chart summary function
            series.QualitativeSummaryOptions.SummaryFunction = "AVERAGE([WorkingDay])";

            ((BarSeriesView)series.View).ColorEach = true;

            ConstantLine line = new ConstantLine("Average Workingday:", series.QualitativeSummaryOptions.SummaryFunction);
            diagram.AxisY.ConstantLines.Add(line);
```

I want to add constantline in my chartcontrol showing average of workingday but it doesn't show
in chart. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to

> add constantline in my chartcontrol showing average of workingday.

This code uses a different approach for instantiating the `ConstantLine`. To keep the example to a minimum, the series is created ad hoc for testing purposes only. The answer should still work with your bound data table.

---

[image: screenshot]

```
public MainForm() =>InitializeComponent();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // Specify data members to bind the chart's series template.
    Series series = new Series("series", ViewType.Bar);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        series.Points.AddPoint(
            argument: i, 
            value: 1 + (0.25 - _rando.NextDouble()));
    }
    chartControl1.Series.Add(series);

    // Specify the template's series view.
    chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.View = new StackedBarSeriesView();
    ((BarSeriesView)series.View).ColorEach = true;

    // register chart summary function
    // series.QualitativeSummaryOptions.SummaryFunction = "AVERAGE([WorkingDay])";
    // ConstantLine line = new ConstantLine("Average Workingday:", series.QualitativeSummaryOptions.SummaryFunction);

    ConstantLine line = new ConstantLine
    {
        Name= "Average Working Day",
        AxisValue = series.Points.Average(_ => _.NumericalValue),
        Color = Color.Red,
    };

    XYDiagram diagram = chartControl1.Diagram as XYDiagram;
    diagram.AxisY.ConstantLines.Add(line);
}
Random _rando = new Random();
```

Comment: AxisValue = series.Points.Average(_ => _.NumericalValue) what should I write in this code when I use my code?

Comment: If it would be helpful, you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/chart-control-with-constant-line.git) the code I used to test the answer. I think the DevExpress references will all work hopefully :) The main difference is that you'll be using your data table instead of the simulated source I made but the other code should be the same.

Comment: Oh I see.. but I have an error that Compiler Error CS1061 in NumericalValue that 'ISeriesPoint doesn't have 'NumericalValue' definition or method.

Comment: If compiler thinks it's `ISeriesPoint` maybe try this cast: `AxisValue = series.Points.Cast<IDataPoint>().Average(_ => _.NumericalValue)` because we're relying on it being an `IDataPoint`.